# Retagging for new products: terminal-services vs. remote-desktop-services

Tags: discussion, retag-request

As I recently had experience with, Microsoft changed the name of [terminal-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) (Windows Server 2003) to [remote-desktop-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop-services) (Windows Server 2008). At time of writing, these tags have 111 and 47 questions respectively; the much broader [remote-desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) tag has 519 questions (with overlap to the other two tags) but there are potentially only a small number which cover the exact same area (RDP access to a multi-user Windows server); speaking of which, [rdp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rdp) has 271 questions.

For any Windows Server experts (or otherwise): should these tags be unified (via synonyms?), or are they distinctly different subject areas which require distinct tags?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, tough call but great pickup.

RDS is an evolution of TS. 95% of users will only use the TS features of RDS, but whose to know what will happen in the future.

[remote-desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) and [rdp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rdp) are definately candidates for synonyms, although RDP is technically a protocol, and Terminal Services and RDS and others (like Thinprint etc) are applications that run on RDP. However I'm guessing that 100% of the [rdp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rdp) questions actually mean [remote-desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop).

<strike>I'll make the [rds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rds) -> [remote-desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) merge now, and leave the merge of the rest up to discussion.</strike>

I just noticed that there's an [rds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rds) and [remote-desktop-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop-services). So now I'm in two minds about what to do, because it could be silly to have [remote-desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) and [remote-desktop-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop-services), we should really have [terminal-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) and [remote-desktop-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop-services) if we're going to have two. I'm more and more convinced they should stay seperate though.

Answer (score 3):

I do have a slight concern with [terminal-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) this is a more generic term that arguably applies to products available to multiple vendors.  I see [terminal-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) as being being about a specific computing concept similar to [firewall](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/firewall), [routing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/routing), or [networking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/networking).

If I where to take a stab at defining it, this tag is about a generic technology where the majority of the computing experience is handled on a server, and only the input/output is handled by the client device.  This means X11, Citrix, Nomachine, LTSP, VDI, and many other technologies fit under this tag.

I would like to see most of the questions in [terminal-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) re-tagged at least include the a vendor specific tag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a real difference between Terminal Services and Remote Desktop Services but those are both services, whereas Remote Desktop Protocol is a protocol and therefore quite distinct (when used correctly). RDP should not be bundled with the others because it covers more ground than either of the other two and there are cases where RDP is correct but neither TS nor RDS applies.